# Play sound on command error in terminal

Tags: bash, audio, terminal

I'm the student manager at a college helpdesk, and we extensively use rsync to back up data from users' machines.  However, one problem I've noticed is that a lot of times, we'll have a network connection drop (which leads to any running transfer to our backup server to fail).  Unless someone happens to see the "broken pipe" error, the transfers are just left stalled until someone happens to look in the next day.

My question is this: is there a way that I can get a sound to play if the previous command returns an error?  Solutions on both/either Ubuntu or OS X would be appreciated.  I know about using `&&` for performing a command after a successful run and `;` for simply running another command, but I'm not sure about doing a sound on failure/don't know if `trap` will work consistently on OS X/Ubuntu.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu and OS X both have full featured `bash`, so here are no differences with trap management.

I don't know Ubuntu in detail, but on OS X you can use the next commands:

- `afplay some.mp3` - can play any audio what can play QuickTime so, mp3, wav, aiff etc...
- `say -v Alex "message"` - will to text2speech - read messages with computer generated voice

bot commands is possible to use with:

```
rsync ... || say -v Alex "Hey, Hudston we have an rsync problem at $(hostname)", or
rsync ... || afplay "/Users/me/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Michael Jackson/Bad/01 Bad.m4a"
```

You need to use the `||` for running command with unsuccessful result. Best form is as an function, like:

```
#!/bin/bash

err() {
    say -v Alex "$@"
    afplay "/path/to/music/file.mp3" &
    echo "$@" >&2
    return 1
}

rsync .. || err "rsync failed" || exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in `~/.bash_profile`

```sh
PROMPT_COMMAND='(( $? )) && printf "\a"'
```